# generator of number field inside a given number ring

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If $R$ is a number ring (i.e., a subring of a number field) and $K$ its fraction field. Why can we always find an element $a\in R$ such that $K = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$? Probably I am missing an easy argument.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the ring of algebraic integers of this number field?

Comment: @Dustan Levenstein: the O.P. said the ring of fractions of $R$ is $K$.

Comment: @Bernard ah, yes, I missed that.

Comment: With number ring I just mean an arbitrary subring of a number field (not necessarily its ring of integers). In the case where $R$ equals the ring of integers of $K$ the statement above is true: choose a primitive element $\alpha\in K$ and replace it by a suitable integral multiple.

Comment: You do not mean an arbitrary subring, since you can't take $R = \mathbf Z$ and that is a subring.

Comment: @KCd: Why not? It is a subring of $\mathbb Q$ (which is a number field).

Comment: I meant you do not want to use $R = \mathbf Z$ *in all cases* but such a choice is a subring of every number field, so it fits your comment that $R$ can be an arbitrary subring of a number field. The integers are always a subring, but unless $K = \mathbf Q$ you would not want that choice for $R$.

Comment: @KCd: I think my question stated above is clear: given is an arbitrary subring $R$ of a number field, ...... You can't choose $R$, it is given already. So I don't understand your point.

Comment: Yes, the question is clear but the comment you made is less so (*taken on its own*), because in the comment you wrote about "an arbitrary subring of a number field" and $\mathbf Z$ is a subring of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$, for instance but you do not want to use that subring as explained in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found an easy argument: the ring $R\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q = S^{-1}R\subseteq K$  (where $S$ denotes the multiplicative subset $\mathbb Z-\{0\}$) has finite dimension over $\mathbb Q$, hence it is a field (every  domain finite-dim over a field is a field). But then necessarily $S^{-1}R = K$. In particular every element of $K$ can be written as $r/k$ with $r\in R$ and $k\in \mathbb Z-\{0\}$.

Comment: So which $\alpha$ gives you $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Comment: @RobArthan You pick a primitive element of $K$ over $\mathbb Q$ and write it as a fraction $r/k$ (as described above). Then take $\alpha = r$.